# AngularJS: Issue with interceptors in $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

Im having a weird behavior manipulating a response through $resource with a custom interceptor.

If I use a response interceptor like this :

```
angular.module( 'app.services', [] )
  .factory( 'Product', function( $resource, routesConfig ) {
      return $resource( routesConfig.catalogueEndPointg(), {}, { 
        query: { 
          method :'GET', 
          isArray : false, 
          params : { 
            page : '@currentPage'
          },
          interceptor: {
            response: function( response ) {
              // DO STUFF
              return response;
            }
          },
        } 
      });
    });
```

Then, from my controller :

```
angular.module( 'app.controllers', [])
  .controller( 'DummyController', function( $scope, Product ){
    productsPromise.$promise
      .then(
        // Success
        function ( response ) {
          console.log( response );
        });
  });
```

At this point, this is the output of the console.log( response ) :

[image]

On the response object, I have the data object, as expected, but I also have this resource : Resource object which also includes the response data again.

But, if I dont use a interceptor at all; Im getting the expected response :

[image]

I dont understand this behavior and Im concern about perform or memory issues.

Can somebody clarify this ?

PS: I need to use interceptors, because I have to modify the response from server.

Comment: Try to compare the references of response.data and response.resource.data, if these two are same there should not be any issues with memory.

Comment: I just check it via : console.log( response.data.data === response.resource.data ) and also via console.log( response.data.data == response.resource.data ); both returns true, so I guess they both have the same references, thus, no issues with memory, but anyway, why this behavior ? I cant find nothing on the documentation and I dont like when "weird" things happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracted from github issue -> answered by gkalpak -> [answer](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11201#issuecomment-76714521)

---

The default interceptor won't add any property (the property is already there, added by `ngResource` for reasons I'll explain shortly). All the interceptor does is return `response.resource` instead of `response` or `response.data`.

### How `ngResource` "works":

Consider the following code:

```
var User = $resource(...);
var userInstance = User.get({id: 1});
// Request still pending | `userInstance` is an instance of `User`
// ...
// Response arrived | `userInstance` updated with new fields (from `response.data`)
```

Basically, when you create a resource instance, `User.get()` (or whatever method you use) returns an object (or an array if `isArray: true`), which is an instance of `User`.
`$resource` keeps a reference of this returned `userInstance`, so it can populate it with more properties as soon as the response arrives (basically, it will be extending `userInstance` with `response.data`).

---

#### Why does `ngResource` do this

This is a very handy feature of `ngResource` that allows you to avoid some boilerplate, when retrieving data that need to be displayed in views. Compare the following snippets:

```
<!-- In the view -->
Current user: {{ user.username }} &lt;{{ user.email }}&gt;

// Now, you can do this:
$scope.user = User.get({id: 1});

// You DON'T need to do this:
User.get({id: 1}).$promise.then(function (user) {
  $scope.user = user;
});
```

---

#### Why not directly return `resource`

So, why rely on a default interceptor for returning `response.resource` ? Why not have `$resource` directly return `resource` in the firt place (instead of attaching it to `response`) ?
This is for allowing you to use custom interceptors that do have access to other response-related data (such as `headers`, `status` etc), while still only returning `resource` if you choose not to use a custom interceptor.

---

PS: Leaving this here in order to provide an answer. Maybe somebody will check this.

Comment: +1. Took the liberty to fix formatting/code highlighting + a few grammatical errors :) (Updated the GitHub answer as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know the reason for this behavior.

ngResource is intentionally doing this.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]